# What data fields are available to me at receipt template

Tags: civicontribute, receipts, templates, fields

My CiviCRM 5.16.
When I try to add fields to receipt template, I discovered that I could add {$line.contribution_id} which shows the record ID of the contribution.
But adding {$line.creditnote_id} (which is also a field in table civicrm_contribution) shows nothing.

How can I know (or change) the data fields that are available for me to show on the receipts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the message template, put this in the `<body>` section of the html format section and then send yourself a contribution receipt.

```
{assign_debug_info}
<table id="table_assigned_vars">
    {section name=vars loop=$_debug_keys}
        <tr class="{cycle values="odd,even"}">
            <th>{ldelim}${$_debug_keys[vars]|escape:'html'}{rdelim}</th>
            <td>{$_debug_vals[vars]|@debug_print_var}</td></tr>
    {/section}
</table>
```

This does basically the same thing as using `{debug}` in regular smarty templates to see the variables in the UI.